# Screen Capture Programmatically Not working for content menu and ringtone preference fragment in Android

Tags: android, screen-capture

I am using [Falcon Android Screenshot library](https://github.com/jraska/Falcon) to take screen shot of app programmatically. The library works like a charm in capturing activities and dialogs , but fails to capture context menu and Ringtone Preference. I tried to get properties of Window Manager , Window , Phone Window and Decor View, but no luck.

Observation:
1: The Ringtone Preference Fragment do not get added to application windows manager - 'mRoots' or 'mViews'.
2: Works well with CheckBoxPreference and ListPreference.
2: There is no change to root layout 'mView' of active Screen.
3: Tried to read 'mActionModePopup' and 'mActionModeView' of decor view . But app hangs at this point.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: why dont u use default screen capture ?

Comment: What is the default screen capture method?

Answer (score 0):

First, get root view from current activity:

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Second, capture the root view:
```

Then get the bitmap,

```
public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
       View screenView = view.getRootView();
       screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
       screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
       return bitmap;
 }
```

Comment: I have used the above code in my project.  But there is no change in root view when context menu . popup windows is displayed. Please look at my observations. Thanks.

Comment: Does not solve the problem, of some windows not being captured in screnshot.